# How to detect if scrollbar takes up space in Chrome for OS X?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have some code that assumes the vertical scrollbar width for OS X to be 15px and does some layout accordingly.

This works for Mac. However, on the Macbook, Chrome's scrollbar doesn't seem to take up any extra space. It is dispayed as overlay on the page content. This causes the layout to be a bit distorted.

Is there any way I can detect if the scrollbar has reserved space or not for Chrome across Apple desktops/laptops?

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width

Comment: @Unlockedluca: Hi, Thanks for answering. That's a good solution, and I looked into it. However, I'm not sure I'm allowed to modify the client's page. I'm laying out my iFrames on someone else's website. So I'm looking for a more strightforward solution.

Comment: @Unlockedluca: I found a way to make your link's solution work. If you post as an answer, I might accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code from [here:](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width)

First you define some style guides in your stylesheet:

```
/* way the hell off screen */
.scrollbar-measure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

And than in your javascript you start like that:

```
// Create the measurement node
var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

// Get the scrollbar width
var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
console.warn(scrollbarWidth); // Mac:  15

// Delete the DIV 
document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worth noting that this doesn't work for IE (shocking). The clientHeight isn't returned properly. I solved it by adding another div inside the first with width 100% and subtracting the two `offsetWidth`s

Comment: Was searching for a solution to this 6 months later and this was the ticket!